# Trying to convert String to JSONObject skips try & catch

Tags: android

I am trying to convert string into JSONObject, but my application skip the try and catch. Here's the code :

```
if(!getUserRegisterInfo().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    retrieveState();
}
```

retrieveState function:

```
private void retrieveState(){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(UserPreferences.getUserRegisterInfo());
        JSONObject row = obj.getJSONObject("UserRegistrationInfo");

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"firstName = " +row.getString("firstName") ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is not throwing any exception, nor Toast is shown, any help would be really valuable for me!

Comment: It's not skipping it is throwing exception :)

Comment: check your logcat view , there will some red lines telling you , what's wrong

Comment: put a toast in your catch too and you will see your lovely toast and edit your heading as json skip try but my catch catches it haha :)

Comment: Did you get any log cat exception?

Comment: this is exception and please check your log cat.

Answer (score 0):

If JsonObject throwing Exception. then your code will never executed the remaining try block.

**Try this**

```
private void retrieveState()
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(UserPreferences.getUserRegisterInfo());
        JSONObject row = obj.getJSONObject("UserRegistrationInfo");

    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Your Message" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```